# Delete row with children from QTreeView with QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I tried

```
 ModelIndexList list = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
uint size = list.size();
if (size>0) {        
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {              
            QModelIndex index = proxyModel->mapToSource(list[i]);
            standardItemModel->removeRow(index.row());
         }
```

It deletes rows with children if i choose root row. If I choose some subtree then only root is deleted and after trying to delete again children that become root application crashes.

Comment: I think you should add your answer and accept it. It's really hard reading the question now since it's hard to tell what is being asked and what were the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing parent parameter in removeRow function. Right code is here:

```
ModelIndexList list = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
uint size = list.size();
if (size>0) {        
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {              
        QModelIndex index = proxyModel->mapToSource(list[i]);
        standardItemModel->removeRow(index.row()
                 /*I was missing this -->*/ , index.parent());
     }
```